# How can i add next and previous button on pager settings jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, pager

How can I show Next and Previous button on Pager Setting?

Here is my code

```
    <PagerSettings ScrollBarPaging="false" PageSize="150" NoRowsMessage="No records to display." />
    <ExportSettings ExportDataRange="All" />
    <AppearanceSettings ShowRowNumbers="true" />
```

Here it displays like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to display pager toolbar like this, but I don't know how

[image]

How can I achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine example.
HTML for table:

```
<div id="TimeReportsGridContainer" class="gridcontainerdiv">
            <table id="TimeReportsGrid"></table>                
            <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;" id="Timereportspager"></div>
</div>
```

and for Grid:

```
$("#TimeReportsGrid").jqGrid({
```

after that

```
pager: $('#Timereportspager'),
pagerpos: 'center',
```